# Retrieving a file from a URL without loading it into RAM first

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Python's `urllib.request` module offers a [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) function which retrieves a URL's content plus some metadata and stores everything in main memory. In environments with limited memory this can quickly result in `MemoryError`s.

There is another function called [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) which seems to do what I am looking for. For some reason, though, the official documentation mentions that it [might become deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface) in the future.

Is there an "official", built-in and non-legacy way for performing a download directly to the local file system? I am aware that this can easily be achieved with third-party libraries such as `requests` but I am working under strict computational & memory constraints and therefore would favor a built-in solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download large file in python with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)

Comment: @zvone Thanks for the reference but I am looking for a way to achieve the same thing without the requests library

Comment: @zepp.lee Why don't you want to use requests?

Comment: @AMC I am writing code to run on very limited (embedded) hardware and therefore every saved dependency counts

Comment: _run on very limited (embedded) hardware_ I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit yourself to Python's standard library, please note that `urlopen` returns `HTTPResponse` objects, which [have methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read) to read the response into memory chunk by chunk. You can buffer chunks of the response in RAM and write it to disk or elsewhere along the way.

The `requests` module makes the whole thing [more streamlined](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow).

Comment: To boot: `urllib.request.urlretrieve` [does exactly this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0846e5d4603434c2bbf8a528677cf1ff3fe29b95/Lib/urllib/request.py#L229), in blocks of 1024*8

Comment: @BradSolomon Very interesting, thank you for the link! Do you by any chance happen to know why there are plans to deprecate `urlretrieve`?